# MySQL Response "OK" With No Results Grid

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I keep getting a response of "OK" with no result grid from this when I have no limit, but when there is a limit of 50000 rows I do get a response with appropriate data in the results grid. I am unsure why. Works without the last two date defining AND's with about 4,000,000 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM `optionsdata`

WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,quote_datetime,expiration) < 7 

AND strike > 250 

AND strike < 290 

AND underlying_ask - strike < 16 

AND underlying_ask - strike > -16

AND quote_datetime >= '2018-01-03 00:00:00' 

AND quote_datetime <= '2018-01-13 00:00:00';
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me.  The only explanation I can conjure is that the "OK" is shown and the query hasn't actually finished executing, hence you don't see any results yet.  When you use `LIMIT 50000` how many records do you get back?

Comment: When I use the LIMIT 50000 I return 50000 row(s) returned.

Comment: OK...is it possible that the query is still executing on the result set of 4 million records?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be what you are looking for but I'm throwing this here in case it helps someone else. I've seen other OK response posts but they usually involve subqueries. Your query is straight forward.

Is either quote_datetime or expiration unsigned integer?

I had an issue where I was subtracting a bigint(20) unsigned with a bigint(21) which resulted in OK. The solution was to cast the bigint(20) unsigned to signed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting a larger unsigned int from another unsigned int (which would otherwise result in a negative number) will result in OK instead of a result set.